# Computing weighted sums of binomial coefficients

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics

This question is a reformulation of 
[Complexity for computing weighted number of paths on integer lattice](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20232/complexity-for-computing-weighted-number-of-paths-on-integer-lattice)

Is there any way to compute in $o(n^2)$ all $n$ sums 
$\sum_{0\leq i \leq j} a_i\binom{j}{i}$ for $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$?